# Using Change sets got an Error at Validating Assignment Rule:

Tags: case, change-set, assignment-rules

[image]Can any one help me out. I have an assignment rule on case object in sandbox as well as in production.Now we have added two rule entries to the same rule based on the profile user in sandbox .Now can i move this rule into production Using change sets.At the page layout we have made the assignment rule as Default tick for few pagelayout on case object.Now when i use changeset i need to select all the pagelatouts in the outbound changeset .

The outbound changeset when well while uploading but in Inbound changeset was un successful.
 At the time of Validation in change set i got an Error on the page layout .I had 3 page layout as Caselayout, Caselayout-Salesuser, Caselayout-Admin .
Error message In field: QuickAction - no QuickAction named SendEmail found for the 2 page layouts Caselayout , Caselayout-Admin.

I shall appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you sure your change set includes everything that the pagelayout/s need? The error message implies that a quick action is missing...

Comment: @Girbot,@Jag:Thanks for your reply.I have checked again ,On case pagelayout i could see a section as Publisher Action created 
Actions in this section appear in the Chatter feed in the full Salesforce site, in the Salesforce1 action bar, and may appear in third party apps that use this page layout.i could see SendEmail button.So i need to select this Action component and related buttons and deploy.

Answer (score 0):

If you have included any new buttons in Page-Layout and if you are including just the Page-Layout without adding the dependencies, Salesforce platform is going to complain about this.

Take another look at you change-set again and validate and include all the dependencies.
Once included, upload it to your Production.

Answer (score 0):

On case pagelayout i could see a section as Publisher Action created  with few buttons SendEmail button.So while deploying i have  selected the Action component and related buttons  and moved into production successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Check the list of components which were part of changeset. If you have added those actions,links, buttons.

Answer (score 0):

In VSCode , remove the tag  for Predefined Case Teams in the AssignmentRule xml and deploy, add that later in the destination , which is easier and only workaround till Salesforce fixes this issue.

[image]